# PHP Crashed EACCELERATOR

Tags: php

Website doesn't load on the shared hosting. In the logs file I see this error:

```
[notice] EACCELERATOR(12593): PHP crashed on opline 12 of main() at ...
```

I've never seen before `PHP crashed error`. What is causing this and how to fix it? Note I don't have access to `php.ini` and in .htaccess of the server I got this:

```
# To set your custom php.ini, add the following line to this file:
# suphp_configpath /home/yourusername/path/to/php.ini
```

So I make `php.ini` in publick_html folder and put into the file this:

```
suphp_configpath /home/myhost/public_html/php.ini
eaccelerator.enable 0
eaccelerator.optimizer 0
```

Then I run `phpinfo();` to see if eaccelator is still on and it is

```
Version 0.9.6.1-ea
Caching Enabled true
Optimizer Enabled   true
Check mtime Enabled true
Memory Size 16,777,152 Bytes
Memory Available    16,772,312 Bytes
Memory Allocated    4,840 Bytes
Cached Scripts  1
Removed Scripts 0
```

So how to turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT.
see: you need to add a path to your custom php.ini TO .htaccess (so webserver  could find it)

.htaccess:

```
suphp_configpath /home/YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE/php.ini
```

/home/YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE/php.ini:

```
eaccelerator.enable 0
eaccelerator.optimizer 0
```

also, contact your hosting provider, if they upgraded something and broken your php install, it's their duty to fix this.

Comment: It is brain new hosting which I never used it before. Just uploaded the website to it and on first run `Error 500`..

Comment: I've added following lines into php.ini but still same

Comment: Made it like this. Still on phpinfo `Caching Enabled true`, `Optimizer Enabled true`, `Check mtime Enabled true`

Comment: seems so. sorry, couldn't help you. what hosting is this btw?

Comment: Thank's for the help anyway. Will try to fix this.. otherwise is unusable hosting for me :)